# DNN: The Web Application Project xxx is configured to use IIS. The Web server "http://dnndev/desktopmodules/xxx/' could not be found."

Tags: iis, iis-6, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

When following a tutorial for setting up a development environment for DotNetNuke modules, creating a new project from the project templates caused the following error:

```
The Web Application Project xxx is configured to use IIS. 
The Web server "http://dnndev/desktopmodules/xxx/' could not be found."
```

How can this be fixed, as the tutorial was followed exactly?

Answer (score 6):

I found two common answers online, which did not work for me but did work for others. I then discovered that I just needed to tweak one of these answers:

1. Make sure that you are running Visual Studio as administrator.
2. Make sure that you have set up a binding for your site in IIS for **dnndev.me**

The KEY part of #2 above, for me, is that when binding was set to *dnndev.me* I could open the module project in Visual Studio, but not the overall DNN installation in a browser. When the binding was set to *www.dnndev.me* I could open the overall DNN installation in a browser, but not the module project in VS...

The answer that worked for me in the end was to have two bindings, both set to port 80, one with the Host Name set to *www.dnndev.me* and the other set to *dnndev.me*

As it took so long to find this answer I wanted to make sure it was here for people to find easily.

Comment: I just found that in the Chris Hammond's templates you just have to set the correct URL in the last step creation form to www.dnndev.me instead of dnndev.me because it have to be the same configured in IIS binding.